# What makes this typography good looking?

Tags: typography, critique

I'm making this poster:

[image]
<sub>[SVG file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FwBda5hkPYb4yoCiLxZXGy3xA7qVcb30/view?usp=sharing)</sub>

Even though I find it's quite a good design, my lack of formal education in graphic design makes me unable to explain why it is a good one. Especially on the text. For example, here are some of my questions:

- The typeface is [Book Antiqua](https://freefontsvault.com/book-antiqua-font-download-free/). Why does it look fit in here? Does the italic title fit the air that the background creates for the viewers? Why? If you need to change the typefaces, what can them be?
- Are the line spacing and the size harmony? How do I know if they are?

In this design I have center-align the text, use white color for grey background.

<sub>Background source: [The Transient Landscape | Cai Guo-Qiang](https://caiguoqiang.com/projects/projects-2019/ngv-transient-landscape/)</sub>

Comment: "Fit" as in good? Sorry slang evolves.. `:)` I know fit means good in slang for some parts of the world, but it's not used in the same manner in the US. Just making certain.

Comment: @Scott - it means good looking in UK slang, but only really works for people, - "a fit bird", "a fit bloke", etc. Stumped me as well.  Not sure what is being asked here TBH.

Comment: Ahh. thanks @BillyKerr I've heard it used in reference to people on UK tv shows... I wasn't sure if it worked as a "general" positive. And "does type fit" works as well as "does type look good".

Comment: It has sexual connotations . . . so no, definitely not general. LOL.  Perhaps lost in google translation?

Comment: .. or it *is* a substitute for "good" in Asia..... Like I posted, we don't even use the UK usage here in the US. So who knows :)

Comment: Yeah I just mean "good looking". "only really works for people", "has sexual connotations"... Thanks for your correction

Comment: @Scott I'm not sure why the related question isn't related. In my understanding this question is a case of that question for you to practice the theory. After it is removed I don't see it on the related question panel on my side

Comment: Ooker, the thing is questions should be self contained. This question can be answered without ever looking at any "related" links you include. Users can view your profile if they want to see other questions you've asked. Essentially, the link doesn't add to the question at all. It's merely a "rabbit hole" where users click the link and forget the original question. Basic premise of user focus... don't *give* users a method to move away from your desired goal (an answer).

Comment: Let Stack's proven algorithms determine what is or is not related.

Comment: Not sure how well it's proven, but that's fair I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line-for-line centering is often a *lazy* choice. That is **not** to say it's always bad. Centering tends to work adequately much of the time and can often be a "quick-fix" in terms of design. Often, designs which are far more interesting visually won't use line centering. Whether it works or not is really more *preference* than anything.

---

The line centering works well with this particular image because of the *image itself*. Essentially the photographer has done 80% of the work for you. The image creates an "hourglass" visual shape. The top is pushing the eye downward, the bottom is pushing the eye upward....

[image]

The visual upside down triangle created by the type simply enforces the push upward.... then the birds/bats shape pushes the eye downward. In addition, the triangle shape subtly continues the eye movement of the birds at the top. Bringing the top shape - the triangle created by the birds - down to the base of the piece. So you've got somewhat juxtaposing movement.

In this case, the line centering actually balances the visuals a bit more. The top of the image is much "heavier" than the bottom without the type. The type is assisting on overall *balance* rather than working against it or appearing superfluous.

[image]

*What's *really* balancing the overall image is that white logo at the bottom.* It's directly counteracting the heavy black at the top of the image. That logo is *visually* as strong as the black at the top. Without that logo, the piece would *not* work as well.

This juxtaposition help keep the eye on the page and "dancing" so to speak. This makes for an intriguing image. It psychologically causes the viewer to keep looking as if there's more to see, when there really isn't.

---

As for the italics, changing typefaces, and all that.. that's all merely *preference*. There are no right or wrong answers to any of that. The only real key here is that the type centering is probably one of the better layout choices here. And that logo placement is critical due to the background image. The other choice with be to try and reverse that type triangle so the point is at the top. This *may* work better, or not. One would have to test it.

I *do* think the spacing you have between the text lines are well done. They seem equidistant and don't create too much or too little white space. Lines are easily tracked visually and prominence is conveyed well without being overpowering.

---

Lastly, I hope you are aware that that *photograph is copyrighted* and using it without permission from the photographer, for something like a book cover or event flier, is an infringement.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. As for the license, yes I'm aware of that, and has already contacted the artist as well as the museum for permission. I know that until I have a permission then I'm not allowed to do so. While I don't mean this as an excuse, I do see that there is a movement to reject the right for this. I'll need to research more